# Can I affect the parent of a DIV's overflow via CSS

Tags: html, css

I would like to have a div attached to the dom that is off screen and not have the browser be able to scroll.

That is simple enough because we can use `overflow:hidden` on the parent of the child element.

My site dynamically appends divs via Javascript. What I would like to happen is if a specific div is appended offscreen for the browser to display the browser scroll bar. If I append another div, for the browser do not display the scroll bar

`overflow` seems to be influenced by the child element.

Is it possible to effect the parent? This code does not exist, but something like

> overflow-parent:hidden

For example, assuming your resolution is less than 2500px, this shows the div needs to be scrolled too. Without adding CSS that impacts `b` parent (`body`, so `body{overflow: hidden;}` is not accepted), how do I prevent scrolling?

```css
.b {
  position: absolute;
  left: 2500px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="b">asf kkk</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Can you provide a code snippet

Comment: I have given a code example of something but, I am not sure how helpful it will be

Comment: Why can you not apply styles to body here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't control the parent element using *standard* css. However you can set the `div` itself to be `position: fixed` and then it won't affect scroll bar of parent.

```css
.b {
  position: fixed;
  left: 2500px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <h1>scroll right if you can</h1>
  <div class="b">asf kkk</div>

</body>
```